# PHP inheritance: Don't repeat yourself vs. one class fits all

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, traits

I have a set of classes that inherit functionality, depending on what they do. They are screen elements:

Some examples would be:
`ScreenElement_Text_Area extends ScreenElement_Text extends ScreenElement`
`ScreenElement_Text_Text extends ScreenElement_Text extends ScreenElement`
`ScreenElement_Date_ddmmyyyyhhmm extends ScreenElement_Date extends ScreenElement`

Inheritance enables me to specify different behaviour (HTML code, style, validation) without repeating myself. Trivial example:

`ScreenElement::getTitle()`
`ScreenElement::getValue()`
`ScreenElement_Text::getMaxChars()`
`ScreenElement_Text_Money::getCurrency()`

A problem is that these classes are now being used in different contexts than what they were originally intended (which was describing parts of forms): For example, as columns in tables or to describe information appearing in a calendar. Each context adds methods and properties to the classes that other usages don't need. Example:

When used in a form: `getFormElement()`
When used in a table: `calculateColumnWidth()`
When used in a calendar: `getStartTime()`

I now ask myself how to reduce the growing complexity! I'd like smaller, more specialized classes, but would not like to multiply the number of classes nor to duplicate code, but I can't get my head around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution, to avoid manipulating too complex structure, could be to use a [Facade pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern). That is, for example: add the interfaces `IScreenElement_Text_Area_Form`, `IScreenElement_Text_Area_Table` and `IScreenElement_Text_Area_Calendar`.

Have `ScreenElement_Text_Area` implement those 3 interfaces, but only use the most relevant interface in a given context.

That way, a form will only manipulate a `ScreenElement_Text_Area` through an `IScreenElement_Text_Area_Form`, so it will only be able to access `getFormElement()`, but not the other two methods.

That being said, it's just one possible solution. You could also, for example, want to have a look at [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).